# jQuery add leading 0. "0" + varName.slice(-2) doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery

In my code, I used

```
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var mins = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var sec = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

to get days, hours, minutes and seconds. I want to add a leading 0 to the number when is less than 10. I tried

```
$(".mins").html('0'+ mins).slice(-2);
```

but the output is three digits (e.g. 30 -> 030).
But I don't want to have a leading 0 when it's two digits, only add it when it's one digit.

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript as of ECMAScript 2017, String has had a function just for this:

`String.padStart(targetLength,padString)`

`targetLength` being the length you want your string to be and `padString` being the character you want to pad with.

That said `mins` is of type Number so you'll have to convert to String to access this function... Easy way is `mins.toString()` but this is because from your particular case we know for sure mins is of type Number (or NaN), if someone else reading has a similar but different case, you can always do `(mins+"")` to ensure coercion to String (still won't protect against NaN).

Now to actual usage:

```
// padStart of 2 will be 2 min...
$(".mins").html(mins.toString().padStart(2, "0")); // 30, 03, 303, etc...
```

Now if you can't rely on knowing you're running on 2017 good news! There are polyfills! Polyfills basically check if the current JavaScript version knows of the function if not writes them.

Courtesy of [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)

You need the second, but the second needs the first...

[String.prototype.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) and [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Comment: This is great! I use `$(".days").text(days.toString().padStart(2, "0"));` and it adds a leading to day when day < 10. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. You know, if my, or anyone else's answer helped you, you could give us up votes or accept an answer. It is the traditional thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery also has a [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method and you are slicing the jQuery object not the string. Note you have closed `html()` and chained `slice()` after it

Change to:

```
$(".mins").text( ('0'+ mins).slice(-2) );
```

Or for readibility:

```
mins = ('0'+ mins).slice(-2);
$(".mins").text(mins);
```

Comment: Great! It works for hours, mins and sec! How about days? Day can have 3 digits. But if I use `$(".days").html(('0'+ days).slice(-2));`  it only shows 2 digits...which is not correct in some cases...         `$(".days").html(('0'+ days).slice(-3));` is not a right solution either... what can I do for day?

Comment: and what's the different between $().html() vs $().text() ?

Comment: Why do you need to pad days?

Comment: I am making a countdown timer, so I want to know how to pad days as well.

Comment: So get days string length to figure out how much to pad

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solutions

1. `$(".mins").text( ('0'+ mins).slice(-2) ); //add leading 0 when minute is < 10.` But this method doesn't work for days.
2. So in order to add a leading to day, I use `$(".days").text(days.toString().padStart(2, "0"));` When day is three or two digits, the output is "as is". When day is < 10, it adds a leading 0.

So I decided to use `.toString().padStart(2, "0"));` for all my days, hours, mins, and sec.

Thank you for those who helped me!